# Reuse database-connection (PDO) in PHP-file sent by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, variables, code-reuse, onkeyup

I want to check on every key-up, if a username is available or already stored in the database. I use a JS-function with he html-tag onkeyup. In the JS-Function I use AJAX asynchronously to open a database-connection, select the usernames and return, if the specific username has been found.

I couldn't figure out and haven't found any similar request on how to reuse the database-variable (PDO, SQLLite3). At the moment I have to initiate and call a database connection on every key up. Thinking in bigger user-numbers this could be heavy workload for the database, right? Is there a better way to use AJAX asynchronously and make a call to the database?

The HTML-Code:

```
<input id="register_username" type="text" onkeyup="checkUsernameOfRegisterForm();" required>
```

The JS-Function:

```
function checkUsernameOfRegisterForm() {
    var currentText = $('#register_username').val();
    usernameLengthOk = checkUsernameLength(currentText);

    showIfUsernameIsTaken(currentText);
}

function showIfUsernameIsTaken(str) {
    usernameAvailable = false;
    updateButton(); // blocks the form-Button, if on *Available is false
    $.post('ajax/getUsernameAvailable.php', {q:str}, function (data, status) { // TODO kann status weg?
        usernameAvailable = data === '';
        updateButton();
    });
}
```

The getUsernameAvailable.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$result = "";
try {
    $dsn = "sqlite:../sqlite-pdo.db";
    $db = new PDO($dsn); // how can I reuse the $db of other php-files? global doesnt work.
    $allUsernames = $db->query("SELECT ownUsername FROM usertable");
    foreach($allUsernames as $name) {
        $ownUsername = strtolower($name['ownUsername']);
        $lowerQ = strtolower($q);
        if (strcmp($ownUsername, $lowerQ) === 0) {
            $result = $q;
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $exception) {}

echo $result;
```

Comment: You can make your connection persistent by using `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true`.
A better practice is to query your database `onblur` or set a timeout for your keyup

Comment: Depending on the amount of users it might actually make sense to load all the usernames for this. That way you can have an instant array lookup in JS when typing instead of going through n requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache results in the back-end of your application with help of php, 
by storing it temporary in session variable for user. 
You can cache negative results in the front-end part of your application with Javascript, so that way new request is not made for same username typed again.

Also, it is bad practice to make the request to server every time user types some key. 
In Javascript, add some delay for server request, and count at least 4 characters, or what is minimum number of characters for username of your app. 
You can also save some server usage by validating username, so make request only when username fulfills some criteria - Minimum number of characters, allowed type of characters, if same request was made before for same username.

This is not a replacement for php validation of data, so you need to do that as well.

When mentioning this, you should be careful of what you pass to db query, since you pass directly non validated and non sanitized data.

Answer (score 0):

By sending an ajax call to your separate php script you create a new process on the server which delivers both, your frontend file and the handling script. There is no direct way to exchange the database-connection.

If you want to reuse a persistant connection you should for example change the routing of your sites in that way that all requests are redirected to e.g. "main.php". In this file your can instantiate a perstistant pdo-connection which can be reused in the view and the servers-side request-processing files.

An example for such a class:

```
class CC_DBV {

private static $mysqlhost; 
private static $mysqluser; 
private static $mysqlpwd; 
public static $mysqldb;
private static $db;
private static $mysqlport;


function __construct() {


    // ini File einlesen
    $globSettings = parse_ini_file(_ROOTV_.'cfg/main.ini',true);

    // Datenbankverbindung
    self::$mysqlhost = $globSettings ['db_settings']['host'];                   // MySQL-Host aus Config Datei
    self::$mysqluser = $globSettings ['db_settings']['db_user'];        // MySQL-User aus Config Datei
    self::$mysqlpwd = $globSettings ['db_settings']['db_pswd'];         // Passwort aus Config Datei
    self::$mysqldb = $globSettings ['db_settings']['db'];                       // Datenbank aus Config Datei
    self::$mysqlport = $globSettings ['db_settings']['port'];                   // Datenbank aus Config Datei

}

public function getInstance( ) { 
        if(!self::$db) { 

            try{

                self::$db = new \PDO( 
                        'mysql:host='.self::$mysqlhost.';dbname='.self::$mysqldb.';port='.self::$mysqlport, 
                        self::$mysqluser, 
                        self::$mysqlpwd, 
                        array( 
                                \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
                                \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ,
                                \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
                        ) 
                ); 
                //self::$db->exec("SET NAMES utf8"); 

                return self::$db; 

            }catch (\PDOException $e){
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }

        }else{
            return self::$db;
        }

}
```

}

To use it you do something like this:

```
$conn = new CC_DBV(); // you can use this connection multiple times, it's persistant.
$inst = $conn->getInstance(); // create or get the instance of the opened connection
$stmnt = $inst->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE xyz = :VAR1"); // prepare statement with placeholder(s)
$v = array(':VAR1' => 'aValue'); // set up an array with corresponding values
$r1 = $stmnt->execute($v); // execute statement with values
if(!$r1){ echo "PANICMODE";}else{ var_dump($stmnt->fetchAll()));
```